# element name and complex type name are same

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I have an xsd, in which each element name and its complex type name are same. This creates problem when I am generating the Java from xsd using JAXB. This xsd has been provided by external service provider. Is the XSD wrong or I am doing something wrong in generating the xsd. Following is the sample of the xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="Discounts" type="Discounts"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Discounts">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="listWithSizeAttribute">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Discounttest" type="Discounttest"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Whenever I generate the Java object using JAXB, i get the error which says duplicate element Discounts. The entire xsd is full of such elements. Hence, I think something is wrong at my side.

Thanks,
Akshay

Answer (score 0):

**XML Schema**

There isn't a problem when a global element and a complex type have the same name.  I have flushed out your XML schema to make it valid so that I can run a schema compile on it.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Discounts" type="Discounts" />
    <xs:complexType name="listWithSizeAttribute" />
    <xs:complexType name="Discounttest" />
    <xs:complexType name="Discounts">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="listWithSizeAttribute">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
                        name="Discounttest" type="Discounttest" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Discounts**

A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation generates Java classes for complex types, so you a class will be generated for the `Discounts` complex type.

```
package forum11981855;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Discounts", propOrder = {
    "discounttest"
})
public class Discounts
    extends ListWithSizeAttribute
{

    @XmlElement(name = "Discounttest")
    protected List<Discounttest> discounttest;

    public List<Discounttest> getDiscounttest() {
        if (discounttest == null) {
            discounttest = new ArrayList<Discounttest>();
        }
        return this.discounttest;
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

An `@XmlElementDecl` annotation will be generated on the `ObjectFactory` class corresponding to the global element `Discounts`.

```
package forum11981855;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Discounts_QNAME = new QName("", "Discounts");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public Discounttest createDiscounttest() {
        return new Discounttest();
    }

    public Discounts createDiscounts() {
        return new Discounts();
    }

    public ListWithSizeAttribute createListWithSizeAttribute() {
        return new ListWithSizeAttribute();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "Discounts")
    public JAXBElement<Discounts> createDiscounts(Discounts value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Discounts>(_Discounts_QNAME, Discounts.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html